# Javascript code for detecting closing tab or browser without impacting other functionality

Tags: javascript

I want a javascript code snippet which will detect while closing the tab or closing the browser and should not activate event when go to other link or download any file any idea ? I saw there are lot of threads but didn't get the solution i tried this

```
a)
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
      var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

      (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
      return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
    });
b)
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Do you really want to close?";
};
```

but its breaking other functionality(downloading file on click of anchor). It shouldn't be triggered when browser get refresh or opening link or downloading any file.Any Idea on this?

Comment: Do your download `<a>`s use the _download_ attribute, or does the browser only find out it will be a download by the server's response headers?

Comment: thanks paul for your reply..in my application they are lot of widget which i am using for downloading file (anchor,hyperlink,fileupload,filedownload.etc).which is breaking if i add the above code snippet

Comment: It seems like you would need to set some flags to let this handler know whether or not it should do anything, e.g. clicking a link you know will be a download sets a "do not ask about unload" flag and sets a _setTimeout_ for ~`300ms` to remove this flag. Then, if the _unload_ event fires, your handler looks to see if this flag is true before asking the user